# Display success message after wp_update_post

Tags: plugins, wp-update-post

I want to display a success message on updating a form from front-end using `wp_update_post` at the top of the form.

I use below on edit page

```
$post_id = wp_update_post($edit_post);
```

and defined function

```
function write_here_show_success_messages( $success_msg ) {
    echo '<div class="form-success">';
    echo '<span>'.$success_msg.'</span><br/>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

How do I execute this function when the form is updated at the top of the form(or specific location on the page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wp_update_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Return)

> The ID of the post if the post is successfully updated in the
>   database. Otherwise returns 0.

So just test again that.

```
if ( $post_id != 0 ) { // success!
    write_here_show_success_messages();
}
```

Or you can use an action.

```
<?php
/** use action for success message **/
if ( $post_id != 0 ) { // success!
    add_action('form_message', 'write_here_show_success_messages' );
}
?>
<div>
  <?php do_action('form_message'); ?>
  <form>
     <!-- form contents -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works but it shows the message on the top of the HTML page. How do I show this message in the DIV I want it to appear?

Comment: Place it within the div where you want to display the message. Be sure to wrap it in php tags. 
    `<?php if ( $post_id != 0 ) { //do message } ?>
     <form> // form content </form>`

Comment: I move entire `if ( $post_id != 0 ) { 
                write_here_show_success_messages( 'Update Post' );
            } ` to the top of the Form but it does not work. I must of doing something wrong here..

Comment: Try using an action https://gist.github.com/nunotmp/5cec9f7021c1ecb5a865

Comment: No problem. I added the `add_action` snippet to the answer. Glad to help.